# Как использовать несколько звуковых потоков в проекте?

Tags: c#, .net, аудио

У меня есть проект в Visual Studio 2013. в нем есть элементы в цикле они прокручиваются и сравниваются между собой, мне нужно, чтобы при положительном сравнении выдавался звук, например бибик, а при другом условии выдавался другой звук. и такий условий например N количество и соответственно N количество звуков.

Вот пример который не работает:

```
SoundPlayer repulsion = new SoundPlayer();

private void playSound(string wth2play = "")
{
    if (soundEnabled == true)
    {
        switch (wth2play)
        {
            case "colision":
                repulsion.Stream = Properties.Resources.clap;
                break;
            case "myObjClash":

                break;
            case "getQuestion":
                repulsion.Stream = Properties.Resources.getQuest;
                break;
        }
        //repulsion.IsLooped = true;
        repulsion.Play();


        repulsion.Stream = null;

    }
}
```

Comment: А что конкретно не работает? У вас с ресурсами все в порядке? С звуковыми файлами?

Comment: При цикле, у меня например бегают объекты по полю и когда сталкиваются играет семпл. Мне нужно по мимо семпла столкновения, нужно когда сталкиваются объекты с определенным типом играл другой звук

Comment: То есть у вас проблема одновременного проигрывания нескольких файлов?

Comment: да мне нужно, чтобы все файлы звуковые файлы могли играть паралельно. независимо друг от друга. А на данный момент возможно играть только одного файла, остальные выдают ошибку

Answer (score 2):

Вместо `System.Media.SoundPlayer` воспользуйтесь `System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer`. Он поддерживает параллельное воспроизведение файлов. Он родом из WPF, поэтому вам понадобится подключить сборки WPF: WindowsCore, PresentationCore.

```
var player = new MediaPlayer();
player.Open(new Uri(fileName));
player.Play();
```

Comment: Как объявить WindowsCore PresentationCore. Я указал в Solution Explorer add reference, Presentation Core 4.0, а пространство имен using system.media.animation этого достаточно?

Comment: и мне интересно fileName нужно указывать путь Properties.Resources.clap; или полный физический путь?

Comment: Нода проекта проекта в Solution Explorer > правый клик по References > Add Reference > Assembles > Framework > поставить галки PresentationCore и WindowsBase. `using System.Windows.Media`. Путь может быть абсолютным или относительным в файловой системе,  [URI схемы pack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/aa970069.aspx) для получения ресурсов (в WPF и WinForms разные способы внедрения ресурсов в приложение: Embedded Resource и Resource, общий Content), URI веб-ресурса (HTTP(s), FTP и др.).

Comment: Объясните не сведущему, не могу понять как использовать звуковые файлы из Resources . кучу методов использовал. неполучается. мне нужно использовать файл, чтобы он независел от пути его происхождения типа C:\windows\media\sound.wav. Пытался так, но нихрена неработает new Uri("file://Distance/Resources/clap.wav")

Comment: @jcmax Оформите проблемы работы с ресурсами отдельным вопросом, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Даже несколько экземпляров `System.Media.SoundPlayer` не будут проигрывать одновременно.

---

Предложения по улучшению кода:

```
SoundPlayer soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer();
Dictionary<string, Stream> selector = new Dictionary<string, Stream>();

// Вызываем один раз при старте
private void Init()
{
    selector.Add("colision", Properties.Resources.clap);
    selector.Add("getQuestion", Properties.Resources.getQuest);
    //...
}

private void PlaySound(string wth2play = "")
{
    if (!soundEnabled) return;

    if (selector.ContainsKey(wth2play))
    {
        soundPlayer.Stream = selector[wth2play];
        soundPlayer.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Не работает к сожалению : ( выдает ошибку со словарем cant convert Stream to unnamed.IO. Stream....